# c++ - Archive files present in different directories and accessing single files

Tags: c++, unix, tar, archive

I have many text files that are located in different directories -

```
dir1/.../textfiles/<various .txt files>
dir2/.../textfiles/<various .txt files>
```

and so on...

I need a c++ solution to compress and archive all these files present in different directories. I also need a way to search, decompress and open only a particular file in this archive.

One solution I can think of is to use system calls to create a `tar` archive.
I actually want a purely C++ based solution to this problem that is simple and fast and gives the desired result.

I searched a lot about this on the internet and found a few solutions like using Chilkat or libtar libraries but I do not intend to use them.

Another one that I found out is [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/54836/).

Is there any simple C++ solution to this problem?

Comment: If you use a library or a framework, yes, otherwise I'm afraid there is no simple and portable way to do it (depending on your definition of "simple"). Moreover, this question may be too broad for SO.

Comment: Why not libtar? It's a simple solution to this problem. What do you mean with _purely C++ based solution_? Chilkat seems like a overkill. It's a large library for a small problem. Without libraries you would have to implement your own protocol.

Comment: By purely c++ based solution I meant - not relying on system calls to use unix tar utility. I wanted to find out if there is a simple way to do it without using any of these libraries. But just as @Fareanor mentioned there is no simiple or portable way, I may have to use libtar.